# Python requests library can't specify JSON key on HTTP POST

Tags: python, json, flask, python-requests

I have REST API that has creation action `/entries` (only if there is a HTTP POST)

*When I'm performing `POST` request from my `Flask` application:*

I have to do this

```
@application.route("/entries/new")
def new():
    headers = {'Authorization': session.get('auth_token')}
    postData = {'title': 'Ace of Base'}
    r = requests.post(API_ENDPOINT + "/entries", json=json.dumps(postData), headers=headers).json()

    return r
```

to get posted these `Parameters`

```
Parameters: {"_json"=>"{\"title\": \"Ace of Base\"}", "entry"=>{}}
```

Problem is in `"_json"` part. I need everything that is inside of `"_json"` part to go to `"entry"=>{}` part like so

```
"entry"=>{\"title\": \"Ace of Base\"}
```

What could cause this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: `json=json.dumps(postData)` - shouldn't that be `json=postData`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe YES! Thanks you. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the data parameter

```
@application.route("/entries/new")
def new():
    headers = {'Authorization': session.get('auth_token')}
    postData = {'title': 'Ace of Base'}
    r = requests.post(API_ENDPOINT + "/entries", data=postData, headers=headers).json()

    return r
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Same thing happens with `data=...`, additionally it doesn't show a `Parameters` but rather 422 error message (Uprocessable Entity).

Actually as jonsrharpe mentioned in a comment I'd just use `json=postData`

Comment: Try `data=postData` and let me know what happens.

Comment: Well, it worked like a charm too! Maybe we'd correct answer just a little bit and I'd accept this as an answer